# How to retrieve a value from an external page?

Tags: javascript, integration, outsystems

We have the following challenge:

We connect to a webservice of a supplier and in some situations we receive an URL as reaction. On that page a number is "visible". We need that number in our system. We can ask the customer of our application to copy / paste it from a page in an iframe but that's not very customer friendly.

What we tried:

1) Used httprequesthandler.getrequest to receive the html of the page.
    That didn't work because the external page was created using Telerik Kendo (javascript) to fill the page after loading the HTML. So the value is not visible onload of the HTML structure.

2) Javascript
     Javascript reading across different domains isn't allowed in the browser

A solution would be a service or component that renders the page completely and then return the whole page source. But that creates dependencies and also increases reaction time.

Unfortunately the supplier doesn't have a proper return structure through their webservice on their roadmap :(

I hope someone has an idea to tackle this problem...

Comment: Are you able do mimic the way that the page loads the data after onLoad by some means?